# Do We Have Root For ATT Note Edge?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-note

I have googled and have seen where you can gain temporary root, but loose it after reboot, but have dev teams been able to get full root on this device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get permanent root by doing these steps:

Step 1: Once you have temporary root, download a custom recovery and install it because you will be flashing a SuperUser app along with the binaries.

Step 2: Download SuperSu from this link: https://download.chainfire.eu/696/supersu/

Step 3: If can't find any custom recoveries that support your device, then use the  FlashFire app from the Play Store to flash the zip.

Step 4: Reboot into CUSTOM recovery and flash/install the zip.

Step 5: Congratulations!! You now have FULL root access instead of temporary root!

If you are confused or don't understand something, let me know! :)

Comment: In step 3 said "zip" is that the SuperSu you mention in step 2?

Comment: Yes. SuperSu is usually in a zip file to flash for users who can't install SuperSu using the SuperSu app. Sorry, I couldn't make this comment short so I just added some info.

Comment: I do not see any custom recovery for the ATT Version of the Edge.  Do you know of any specifics avaliable?

Comment: If you can't find a custom recovery then you will have to flash the zip with FlashFire. I have also looked to see if I could find a custom recovery that supports your phone but no luck :(

Comment: Grr.  Well I am back to the drawing board since kingroot will not install.

Comment: Did you try Kingo?

Comment: Kingo failed to obtain root also

Comment: Try Baidu root 

Comment: Baidu failed as well.  Looks like ATT locks down devices pretty tight :(

Comment: Which app gave you temporary root?

Comment: Kingroot worked last time I used it.  This time it is not working succesfully.  But I was also on KitKat when KingRoot worked.  I have recently been forced updated to Marshmallow.

Comment: That sucks. You might just have to wait until they have an app that will work for your phone.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Darn you ATT.